# Página carrega sem a query terminar - NodeJS + MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js

Preciso que a página renderize somente quando a consulta retornar algum valor, eu tentei utilizar promise, async, await... mas nada parece dar resultado, a página sempre renderiza e depois os dados são obtidos.

controller:

```
    var conn = app.config.connection();
    var bankModel = new app.app.models.bank_model;
    var capitalMc;

    bankModel.valor_total(conn, function(error, result){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
            res.send(error);
            return;
        }else if(Object.keys(result).length > 0){
            console.log('result' + formatNumber(result[0].valor_total));
            capitalMc = formatNumber(result[0].valor_total);
        }else{
            capitalMc = 'Erro ao carregar os dados.';
            console.log("Erro ao carregar os dados.")
        }
    })
    res.render('template', {title: 'Painel de controle', body: 'dashboard_view', bodyclass: '', capitalMc: capitalMc});
```

model:

```
function bank_model(){

}

bank_model.prototype.valor_total = function(conn, callback){
    var sqlQuery = "SELECT valor_total FROM bank";
    conn.query(sqlQuery, callback);
}

module.exports = function(){

    return bank_model;
}
```

não sei se é uma maneira recomendada ou se tem algo de errado, mas nada funciona! kk

Comment: você já tentou fazer `bank_model.prototype.valor_total = async function(conn, callback) { await conn.query(sqlQuery, callback) }` e chamar com `await bankModel.valor_total(conn,.....)`? (vale lembrar que a sua função no controller precisa ser async tb)

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que está usando o express. Mas se tiver usando outro framework, o resultado é o mesmo.

Você chama "res.render" antes do retorno do callback. Apesar da chamada para "res.render" vim no final, o callback pode retornar bem depois.

Correção:

```
    bankModel.valor_total(conn, function(error, result){
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
            res.send(error);
            return;
        }else if(Object.keys(result).length > 0){
            console.log('result' + formatNumber(result[0].valor_total));
            capitalMc = formatNumber(result[0].valor_total);
            res.render('template', {title: 'Painel de controle', body: 'dashboard_view', bodyclass: '', capitalMc: capitalMc});
        }else{
            capitalMc = 'Erro ao carregar os dados.';
            console.log("Erro ao carregar os dados.")
            res.render('template', {title: 'Painel de controle', body: 'dashboard_view', bodyclass: '', capitalMc: capitalMc});
        }
    })
```

**OBS:** usar return, assim como você está usando, não tem nenhum efeito, pare um pouco para pensar a respeito!

Espero ter ajudado.